# SQL QUERY REQUIRED with respect count in a particular format dealing with NULL and NOT NULL values

Tags: sql

```
ROLE_CAT    SYN_CODE        
ab          2
aaa         4
bcd
aaav
abvx        3
```

**Here**  is the table which has two fields ROLE_CAT and SYN_CODE
1. i want an sql query which gives me the result as

```
ROLE_CAT    COUNT(*)
ab          1
aaa         1
bcd         0
aaav        0
abvx        1
```

This is in case of SYN_CODE IS NOT NULL

```
ROLE_CAT    COUNT(*)
ab          0
aaa         0
bcd         1
aaav        1
abvx        0
```

This is in case of SYN_CODE IS NULL

both the cases should be in single query.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please anyone tell me what was wrong in post before devoting it

Comment: not really clear what you are asking, perhaps post the sql you have tried so far and what is wrong with the results it is producing

Comment: You could also share the database you are using and perhaps format the code with the code `{}` button

Comment: i was giving the sql query as select role_cat,count(SYN_CODE) from table ; and  i was getting only role_cat and count where SYN_CODE was not null ; i wanted where ever SYN_CODE IS NULL , the query should display all the fields and where ever SYN_CODE IS NULL it should give count as 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT role_cat,
       COUNT(syn_code) count1,
       COUNT(*) - COUNT(syn_code) count2
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY role_cat
```

Output:

```
| ROLE_CAT | COUNT1 | COUNT2 |
------------------------------
|      aaa |      1 |      0 |
|     aaav |      0 |      1 |
|       ab |      1 |      0 |
|     abvx |      1 |      0 |
|      bcd |      0 |      1 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3c0f/1)** demo

Comment: thank you peterm , for giving the exact one which i was looking thank you

Comment: @user2535235 You're welcome :) But please learn how to format code when post your questions.